# Taking least significant bit of a byte in cloverETL

Tags: cloveretl, cloud-connect

I'd like to generate a pseudo-random binary number in CloverETL from an integer, as a function that should be computable from outside of CloverETL.

My approach to do that was to :
- salt my integer and hash it with md5
- taking the last bit of this number

But I cannot manage to do the second part with the weird "byte" data type :

```
md5("salt"+str($in.0.myinteger))
```

gives me a byte, but how can I access the last element of this byte?

```
md5("salt"+str($in.0.myinteger))%2
```

doesn't work, and

```
byteAt()
```

is not available in my flavor of CloverETL  (which is called CloudConnect).

How can I access the last significant bit of my md5-ed integer, or more generally of anything with the "byte" type ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use

```
right(byte2str(md5("salt"+str($in.0.myinteger))), 1)
```

I dont understand the use case, so I guess randomBoolean() function is not enough.